# creating matrix for armodel but np.arange returning a none type eventhough the matrix is correct. How to convert to an array? Below is my code so far

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have a function to generate matrix x and y for ar_model to calculate the coefficients using least_square method. However, np.arange when i do print correctly prints the x matrix as it should be but when i convert the np.arange value to an array it's not correct. Please help me how I can correctly generate the array version of the matrix. Thank you!

```
#example lists
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14]

def matrix(x, na): #na is order or armodel
    X = np.array(x)
    N = len(X)
    p = na
    for n in range(p, N):
       u = X[np.arange((n-1),(n-p-1),-1)]
       matrix = print(u)
       array = np.array(matrix) #not correct
       #need to get the negative versions of u
       #but u isnt an array so I wasn't able multiply by -1
       
       #matrix_y
       y = X[na:]
       
    return matrix, array
```

Comment: Can u past here input and output what you get

Comment: `matrix = print(u)` - why are you doing this?  What do you expect `print` to return?  And for your own sanity, don't name a variable the same thing as the function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will correct it @hpaulj.                                                                                                                                                                   This is the output when I do print(u)                                                                                    
[2 1]
[3 2]
[4 3], which is the correct version but is not an array and is nonetype.                                  but when i convert u into an array my output is array([4,3)]